# ASP.NET: ajaxToolkit's HoverMenuExtender slows down sorting in GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview, sorting, performance

I have a GridView inside UpdatePanel and also a HoverMenuExtender declared. GridView also has Paging and Sorting enabled and PageSize is 25.

Right now I'm working on a mockup of the actual application so I'm using a mock DataSet with only 20 records.

Problem is when I try to sort gridView by clicking on a column it's VERY SLOW. It takes about 2-3 seconds to "**sort**" and "**display**" this 20 rows of mock data. But, what we discovered is that if I take out the HoverMenuExtender, everything works as it should. In that case sorting is instant, so problem is more in "**display**" and none in "**sort**".

Is there a way to speed up HoverMenuExtender's rendering or should I just forget about using it?

10x in adv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there is no really a solution for this issue.

I decided not to use this extender with my gridview.

Answer (score 0):

I've come across a similar issue using gridviews and ajax animations with internet explorer.  My ultimate solution was to remove the animations as it was just ridiculously slow for no reason on IE (worked fine in firefox).

What browser are you using?

Comment: Well, I mainly use IE6 for this application, even though I use all (Opera, FF, Safari) to test application, and I must say that what you said is on the right track.

For example in other browsers it does work faster, even though it's still slow. If it takes 3 seconds in IE it takes half as much in other browsers.

I'm still looking for a solution, cause I really, really would like to have this hover menu, but if I have to wait 2 seconds on each sort than it's no good for me.

Comment: I most definitely understand your pain.  Hopefully someone can answer this because I'd love to know a good solution rather than "don't use internet explorer."